# How to deploy Next.js and Express servers on two different ports concurrently on Heroku

Tags: express, heroku, next.js

Here is the deployment challenge that I'm currently facing. I've googled quite extensively and tried a few with no luck.

I have app A that uses express as the server to serve at port 5000. Then I have app B that users Next as the server to serve at port 3000. I wrote some codes to integrate the two apps into one and I'm trying to deploy it onto Heroku. I kept getting deployment failures. Here is my package.json:

```
"scripts": {
"start": "concurrently \" npm run dev \" \" next \" ",
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use Next.js's [Custom Server functionality](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server). Simply define your API routes first and then place `expressApp.all('*', nextHandler)` at the end so that Next catches everything not caught by your API endpoints.

```
const express = require('express');
const next = require('next');

const APIRouter = require('./routes');

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const hostname = 'localhost';
const port = 3000;

const nextApp = next({dev, hostname, port});
const nextHandler = nextApp.getRequestHandler();

const expressApp = express();

nextApp.prepare().then(() => {
  expressApp.use(APIRouter());
  expressApp.all('*', nextHandler);
  expressApp.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`App listening on port ${port}`);
  });
});
```